# Stored Procedure VS. F#

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, f#

For most SP-taught developers, there are no option between Linq and Stored-Procedures/Functions. That's may be true.

However, there are a road junctions nowadays. Before I spending too much time into syntax of F#, i would like more inputs about where the power (and opposite) of F# lies.

How will F# perform on this topic (against SP)?

F# have to communicate with a database on some way. Through Linq2Sql/Entity-app-layer or directly though AnyDbConnection. Nothing new there. But F# have the power of parallellism and less overhead in thier work ([Functional Programming with C#/F#](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/79880.aspx)). Also F# has it's effeciency as a layer for data and machine. Pretty much like C# power of being a layer between human and machine.

- Would I really still let the DB Server handle a request of recurring nodes, or just fetch plain data to F# and handle it there? Encapsulated nice and smoothly as a object method call from C#?
- Would a stored procedure still be the best option for scanning 50 millions of records for finding orphans or a criteria that matching 0,5% of the result?
- Would a SP or function still be best for a simple task as finding next parent node?
- Would a SP still being best to collect a million records of data and return calculated sums and/or periods?

Wouldn't a single f# dll library fully built on the Single responsibility principle being of more use then stored procedures hooked up inside a sql server? There are pros and cons, of course. But what are they?

Comment: What is "crz"?  Please try to spell-check your question, if possible.

Comment: You're asking if SQL code can query a table and do aggregates? As compared to loaing 50 million rows into some F# module and doing it in the client?

Comment: I think he does. Back in the old days there where an article about using F# to parse large xbox log files with, but that was text files and not data in a sql server. I can find this blog post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/apg/archive/2006/11/04/dealing-with-terabytes-with-f.aspx but not the original one.

Comment: crz = of course. GBN: Yes and no. I ask for the chances of earning effeciency and/or stability (best practice of system load). Tests are of help, which (for me) means I first need to learn the language, maybe to find it isn't of use :).

Comment: Huusom, thank's for the contribution. However I don't think text as a fair comparation here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedures are not magically super-fast.  Often, they're actually rather slow.

Many people will downvote this answer providing anecdotal evidence that a stored procedure once made an application faster overall.  However, all of those examples that I've actually seen code for indicate that they totally rethought some bad SQL to package it as an SP.  I submit that the discipline of repackaging bad SQL into a procedure helped more than the SP itself.

Most of your points can't be evaluated without a measured benchmark.

I suggest that you do the following.

1. Write it in F#.
2. Measure it.
3. If it's too slow for your production application, then try some stored procedures to see if it's faster.  If it's fast enough for your production application, then you have your answer, F# worked for you.  For your application.  For your data.  For your architecture.

There's no "general" answer.  Although my benchmarks for some particular kinds of queries indicate that the SP engine is pretty slow compared with Java.  F# will probably be faster than the SP engine also.

The important thing is to make sure that the database -- if it's going to be "pure" data -- is already optimized so that queries like your "scanning 50 millions of records for finding orphans or a criteria that matching 0,5% of the result?" would retrieve the rows as quickly as possible.  This often involves tweaking buffers and array sizes and other elements of the database-to-F# connection.  This usually means that you want a more direct connection so that you can adjust the sizes.

Comment: Thank's for this. I'm on your line, un-proofed though (both way). I think there are several heavy guys "out there" that "know" that SP is "the shit" because SP saved needs and purposes over so many years and systen - where other technics failed. your probably right that there have to be tests.. badly that also means I have to dig into a new language.. while there exist a lot of peoples out there that already did tests like those :).

Answer (score 2):

Databases are efficient for certain tasks (e.g. when they can uses index to search for a specified row), but probably won't be any faster than F# if you need to process all rows and ubdate them (in database) or calculate some new result based on all the data.

As S. Lott suggests, the best option is to try implementing what you need in F# and you'll find out. Parallelism can give you some performance benefits, especially if you're doing some computationally heavy calculations. However, you may still want to store the data in databases, load it and process it in F# (I believe this is how F# was used by adCenter at Microsoft).

Possibly the most important note is that databases give you various guarantees about the consistency of the data - no matter what happens, you'll still end up with consistent state. Implementing this yourself may be tricky (e.g. when updating data), but you need to consider whether you need it or not.

Comment: Interesting, good point there. Consistency, but on what purpose? You talk about what happens to the data from the start-time of the processing, until it finished and will be consumed?

Answer (score 2):

You ask this:

> Would a stored procedure still be the best option for scanning 50 millions of records for finding orphans or a criteria that matching 0,5% of the result?

I take your question to mean 'I have this data in sql server. Should i query it in sql or in client code (F# in this case). Queries like this should absolutely be performed in sql if at all possible. If you're doing it in F#, you're transferring those 50 million rows to the client just to do some aggregation/lookups.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Hi! You understand the question correctly. Can I cache data in Sql Server like I can in C# and F#? Onced transferred, the data is cached. The caching can occur threaded on behind from a specific action. Is the sql server less loaded of aggregate a question within an SP then send a stream of 50 million rows?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a stored procedure or dynamic sql. Performance will be roughly the same. If your aggregations/calculations are simple enough that they can be performed in T-SQL, then you should.

Comment: Oh, and always test and compare. :)

Comment: Thank's! In this case are this question a product of digging into a new language dialect or not. Have you done any tests with F# or are SP simply the thing?

Comment: @dingir on caching: SQL does all kinds of tricks to remember if it can reuse the same answer for a repeated question. Also it will load data from disk (slow) into memory (fast) and keep it there. 50M rows should fit fine. If you provide some more details on what exactly you're doing we can help better. Doing your own caching means that you also need to take care of dropping it when you need to because of changes to the underlying data. SQL does that for you so I'm still on the DB path.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand an SP just means you call some precompiled execution plan, and you can call it through an API, instead of pushing a string to the server. These two save in the order of millseconds, nowhere near a second. For larger queries that difference is negligible. They're good for highfrequency/ throughput stuff (and of course encapsulating complex logic, but that doens't seem to apply here).

Because an SP uses a procompiled plan, it can indeed be slower than a normal query because it no longer checks the statitsics of the underlying data(becuase the execution plan is already compiled.) Since you mention a condition that applies to 0.5% of the rows, this could be important.

In the discussion of SP vs F# I would reword that to 'on the server' vs 'on the client'. If you're talking higher data volumes (50M rows qualifies) my first choice would always be to 'put the mill where the wood is', that means execute on the server if possible. Only if there is some very complicated logic involved you might want to consider F#, but I don't think that applies. Then still I'd prefer to execute that on the server than first drag all those rows over the network (potentially slow).

GJ

Comment: Thank's for sorting things out. I have no purpose by it's own to prefer F#. Though I see a new language coming up, that a lot of peoples seem inadequate resistive to. Perhaps the range of developers helped by F# is tiny. However I feel much more cler about where SP still doing the correct work and where F# is worth a closer look.